# Trying to deploy vault:1.2.4 in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, ubuntu-18.04, vault

I have been trying to bring up a Vault pod in K8!, I am using `vault:1.2.4`
and I have added the capability and config in the `yaml` as mentioned in the official [docker page of vault](https://hub.docker.com/_/vault)
But still, I always get the error:

`Error loading configuration from /vault/config/local.json: stat /vault/config/local.json: no such file or directory`

This is my deployment yaml:

```
  containers:
  - name: vault
    command: ["vault", "server", "-config", "/vault/config/local.json"]
    image: "vault:1.2.4"
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    env:
      - name: VAULT_LOCAL_CONFIG
        value: '{"backend": {"file": {"path": "/vault/file"}}}'
    securityContext:
      capabilities:
        add:
          - IPC_LOCK
    volumeMounts:
      - name: configurations
        mountPath: /vault/config
        subPath: local.json
      - name: vault
        mountPath: /etc/tls
  volumes:
    - name: configurations
      configMap:
        name: vault
    - name: vault
      secret:
        secretName: vault
```

As per the doc, `local.json` should get created, but somehow it
doesn't seem to be created, or created with wrong permissions?!

Tried to pull via `helm` - didn't work (ran into other issues)! Also tried to rebuild a separate container with this config file added, that didn't work either (get the same error)!

I am looking for a simple file based backend, and don't need `Consul` etc.
Please correct me if this deployment config is incorrect, or if I am missing
some steps!

Answer (score 1):

Duh! I was trying harder than I should! the `command:` need not be specified as
it is built into the container. I removed the `command: ["vault"`... line 
and pod could go to `Running` state.